# console.log does not output anything

Tags: node.js

It seems my console does not log to terminal.

```
echo 'console.log("text"):' > test.js
node test.js # nothing shown
node -e 'console.log("text"):' # nothing shown
```

I aptitude reinstalled node and issue persists. npm list is empty. freenode#node.js and google have not helped so far. Thanks!

EDIT

```
node --debug bin/sync.js # not giving anything either
```

EDIT

sys.puts not working either :(

```
npm install sys
node -e 'sys.puts("hola")'
```

EDIT

Tried also with util format, but no luck either

```
util.format('%s:%s', 'foo');
```

EDIT

After reinstalling from github it worked again. I will investigate more and report the bug if reproducable to node mailing list. Thanks for the help! I'll answer my own question in 8 hours because i don't have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't

`'console.log("text"):'`

be

`'console.log("text");'`

Comment: Hi Thank you for your response! Unfortunately it did not work either :(

Comment: Works fine in two environments I tested it in.  Looks like an environmental problem to me.

Comment: i am reinstalling node from github and if it keeps on failing it probably is, as stated by Brent Rockwood, some kind of environment issue